# Nuget, PCL, sl40 sl4 win8 win profile differences

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, portable-class-library

I have PCL with ".NET 4 and higher, Silverlight 4 and higher, Windows Phone 7 and higher, Windows Store apps (Windows 8)" (from project->properties window).

I have Microsoft.Bcl version 1.1.3 installed.
When I want to update the reference to 1.1.6 I see following.

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
>   'portable-net40+sl40+wp+win', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Looking at packages folder I see following:

./Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.3/lib/portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp71

./Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.6/lib/portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp71

Now the questions:

1. What is the difference between sl40 and sl4 profile, win8 and win
   profile and wp and wp71 profile?
2. How can I update Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6 in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft.Bcl is targeting a later version of Windows Phone than your PCL project which is why it is failing to install.

### Framework differences

sl40 and sl4 - same framework

win8 and win - same framework. win means win version 0.0 but NuGet maps this to win8

wp and wp71  - different frameworks. wp means wp version 0.0 but it is equivalent to wp7 by the way NuGet maps the frameworks.

### Updating to Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6

To install Microsoft.Bcl you will need to update your PCL project so it targets wp71 or above. So you can choose to target **Windows Phone 7.5 or later** or **Windows Phone 8 or later**.

If you choose **Windows Phone 7.5 or later** that seems to map to wp71 in Nuget.